# wget: How do I specify both --directory-prefix AND --output-document

Tags: python, wget

When I use either the `-P` or `-O` alone with `wget`, everything works as advertised.

```
$: wget -P "test" http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png
Saving to: `test/logo3w.png'
```

.

```
$: wget -O "google.png" http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png
2012-01-23 21:47:33 (1.20 MB/s) - `google.png' saved [7007/7007]
```

However, combining the two causes `wget` to ignore `-P`.

```
$: wget -P "test" -O "google.png" http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png
2012-01-23 21:47:51 (5.87 MB/s) - `google.png' saved [7007/7007]
```

I've set a variable for both the directory (generated by the last chunk of the URL) and the filename (generated through a counting loop) such that `http://www.google.com/aaa/bbb/ccc` yields `file` = `/directory/filename`, or, for item 1, `/ccc/000.jpg`

When substituting this in to the code:
`Popen(['wget', '-O', file, theImg], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)`
`wget` silently fails (on each iteration of the loop).

When I turn on debugging `-d` and logging `-a log.log`, each iteration prints
`DEBUG output created by Wget 1.13.4 on darwin10.8.0.`

When I remove the `-O` and `file`, the operation proceeds normally.

My question is:
Is there a way to
A) Specify both `-P` *AND* `-O` in `wget` (preferred) or
B) Insert a string to `-O` containing `/`-characters that doesn't cause it to fail?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just pass `dir/000.jpg` to `-O` of `wget`:

```
import subprocess
import os.path

subprocess.Popen(['wget', '-O', os.path.join(directory, filename), theImg])
```

It's not completely clear from your question whether you were already doing something similar to this, but if you were and it still failed, I can think of two reasons:

- The argument to `-O` contains a leading `/`, making `wget` fail because it doesn't have permission to randomly create directories in `/` (root).
- The directory you're telling `wget` to write to doesn't exist. You can make sure it exists by creating it first using `os.mkdir` in the Python standard library.

You can also try removing the arguments `stdout=` and `stderr=` from the `Popen` call so you can see the errors directly, or print them using Python.

Comment: When I try to pass "dir/000.jpg" to "-O", wget returns "no such directory." However, -P will always create the directory if none is found. I *could* implement os.mkdir for this but I was looking for a more elegant solution... Thanks for your input, it's given me some ideas I hadn't considered.

Comment: @JoshWhittington, the solution you're looking for simply isn't possible. `wget` ignores `-P` if `-O` is passed. Personally I don't see anything inelegant about using `os.mkdir`. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

Documentation of wget.download(..):

```
def download(url, out=None, bar=bar_adaptive):
    """High level function, which downloads URL into tmp file in current
    directory and then renames it to filename autodetected from either URL
    or HTTP headers.

    :param bar: function to track download progress (visualize etc.)
    :param out: output filename or directory
    :return:    filename where URL is downloaded to
    """
    ...
```

Use the following call to download file to a specific directory(already existing) with custom filename:

```
wget.download(url, path_to_output_file)
```

If you want a function call to abstract away the directory creation if already not existing, then use:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url, path_to_output_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

This line of code from @Jaydev actually works brilliantly:

`wget.download(url, path_to_output_file)`